# changing a div's hyper link style?

Tags: php, html, css, hyperlink

```
#twitter{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.a:link,a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

im trying to remove text decoration from this picture link.
but its not working.

```
echo '<a class="twitter" href="' . $twitterObj->getAuthorizationUrl() . '"><img src="img/darker.png"></a>';
```

Comment: do you want to remove border from image?

Comment: What is it doing and what do you want it to do? `text-decoration` might not be the right property.

Comment: yes, and when the users hover over the picture, i dnt want to text decoration, just a normal picture that links to something cheers :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of # use .

```
.twitter{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<img src="img/darker.png" border="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use proper css declaration

```
.a img
{
  border:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this extra rule:

```
a:link img,a:hover img{
    border: 0px;
}
```

That will apply the no border rule to any img tags under your links. I also think this rule should work just as well:

```
a img{
    border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a period before your `a:link` (you have it written like this: `.a:link`).

Answer (score 1):

Better use some "CSS Reset" it will generalize most of the margin padding issues to common browsers.

Also in your main css put something like this

> img {border: 0}

Then you don't have to put border 0 in all image tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is looking for an id (#) and in the HTML code you have a class (.). In the second declaration you have a preceding dot that shouldn't be there. So wrapping everything up...

```
a.twitter{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.twitter img {
  border: none;
}
```